# getToken() failed. Status BAD_AUTHENTICATION error

Tags: android, google-play-services

I've found the following error when running my android application in android studio. app couldn't get installed on my device because of this error. Didn't find the solution :(
please help

> Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() failed. 
>   Status BAD_AUTHENTICATION, 
>   Account: , 
>   App:com.android.vending,
>   Service: androidmarket com.google.android.gms.auth.be.account.b.d: Long live credential not
>   available.

Comment: Why there are so many up votes, but no checked answer? What is the solution anyway?

Comment: I am facing this problem too. What is the solution?

Comment: thanks for sharing your issue. it was helpful for me

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue what helped me was that I had wrong credentials in my `google-services.json` file and after getting a new file my problem was fixed.

in the process of resolving this issue I also updated my google play services but I do not think this is necessary .

Comment: What exactly do you mean by saying "wrong credentials", because the "google-services.json" contains a lot informations

Comment: as I said I just got a new `google-services.json` file and replaced it.

Comment: The currently 'google-services.json' that I use it works fine when I test it on the emulator, but when I try it on a physical device I get the "BAD_AUTHENTICATION" error, that's why I'm confused, I'm not sure if I should generate a new one.

Comment: it seems my answer wouldn't work for you. but you should always test google-services on physical devices. it is even possible that emulator haven't read everything on file.

Comment: I think Google's documentation is not good enough and not clear enough to understand how to properly setup the accounts and how to integrate Google Drive.

Comment: it really isn't good enough but if your app is not in production yet deleting and resubmitting the `google-services.json` will cause no problem

Answer (score 4):

I got this error when tried to install app directly from Android Studio.
It was due to certificate mismatch, since I used release certificate for setting up the app in Play Console, while Android Studio signs the app with debug certificate by default.
Installing app via adb resolved the error.

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart#step_4_test_your_game

> Make sure to run an APK that you exported and signed with a
>   certificate that matches one of the certificates you used during the
>   application setup in Google Play Console.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem some days ago. I just compile my whole code in a new project and Problem Solved!!.

Don't know what was the real problem. There is an issue filed [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/253), with no solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons you can get that message:

1. The account you are trying to log on with needs to be re-authenticated on the phone (try a different account)
2. The gms:play-services version is out of date (needs to be 15+ as of Jan 2021)
3. Your app fingerprint is not the right one. You need one for dev builds, different one for prod -- which is different based on how you sign (do you have the final publish key, or does Play store re-sign with the final publish key?)

Follow the Google tutorial and get their stand-alone project, it should take 20 min, and check your setup there. If you are running it with all the right accounts it should work. Then go back to your app.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start

Comment: getting this repeated now on old galaxy tab 2 test device until it crashes: Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account: <ELLIDED:XXXXXXXXXX>, App: com.google.android.gms, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/login_manager. updating and clearing play services data hasn't helped. shows as: libc.so
(Missing BuildId 4a41edc48218b940fbd9785bf4e4abfd) error on crashylitics. I don't use OAuth2 APIs the link mentions.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me, auth errors in ADB, among them:
`android Warn Auth [GoogleAuthUtil] GoogleAuthUtil`

Because, like mentioned above, I had a debug build running on phone previously.  So I fully uninstalled the app on my phone, and the next [Build and Run] ran successfully.

Comment: it's working on me as magic. thank a  lot

Comment: Yep, this worked for me too. A lot of other answers mention things like "I put all my code in a new project", "I restarted my phone", etc and I think they're all basically just resetting the app so a re-install is the best solution imo.

Answer (score 1):

I updated Google Play Services on my phone and stopped receiving the same error. I am importing  com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:9.6.1 and analytics:9.6.1. Not sure if the version running on the device was too low but problem is now resolved but not sure how to prevent this error for users running older versions of Google Play Services.

Answer (score 1):

Tested the other solutions but nothing worked. Rebooted the device and error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

If you using firebase server, As per the firebase updation if you give phone number authentication put your country code before contact number it is mendetory.
example - +91 9999998888

Answer (score 0):

Please try the App with new google credentials or even try creating the whole peoject on console og google play services if you have used it .

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a dependency version problem. I had to update the auth dependency for firebase to the latest one:
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take towards this problem:

1. You may be using a single email to try and log in to google. It may be possible you might have changed the password of the particular email in the recent past. Make sure u remove  your google-email from your phone/emulator. When u re-run your application, you will be asked to enter both email and password credentials.
2. Check if your credentials.json is still valid. Sometimes its possible that your client ID might be removed/corrupted if you have not used your android application for a long time. Make a new one and dont forget to copy-paste it in app folder of Android Project view.

PS: I am new to Android Studio and writing answers on stackoverflow in general. If you are reading this comment please let me know what improvements i can make while answering questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I copied and ran the code in a different project that had priorly worked on simple DB operations of Firebase. Probably it already had the authentication files in place so launching the app was solved there

Answer (score 0):

Mostly your token has gone bad. And needs a new one.
Go to project database > settings > General > download Json file and replace it with the one in the local project directory.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem with updating fingerprints (sha1 or sha256)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with `Microsoft App Center`.

We recently set our pipelines to send **aab** files to App Center, instead of **apk** files.

It seems that our bundle was resigned by **App Center** with some generated keystore. That's how App Center distributed apk files, even though our pipeline uploaded aab files.

In other words: even though our pipeline is using our own **keystore** to sign the aab bundle, in order to distribute through the **App Center**, after sending the `aab` to **App Center**, the `App Center` is creating universal **apks** with another generated keystore.

After rolling back our pipeline to send `apk` instead of `aab`, **Google SignIn** on our **react-native** app with **firebase** was working again.

---

> "When you distribute Android Application Bundle (AAB), App Center generates a universal APK, signs it with a generated signing key, and distributes it to a device."

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/uploading

Comment: I had also checked the `webClientId` required to configure the Google SignIn package. My `webClientId` was already correct.

Comment: I had also checked if the fingerprint of my keystore was correctly set on Firebase Console.

Answer (score 0):

After running `adb logcat`, I saw this issue had to do with one account I was logged in on the device for, and another the play store saved. Restarting and other solutions didn't work.

What worked was removing the accounts entirely from the device in the play store settings & device settings, and adding back the one I ended up using alone.