# getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Does not let application to start up

Tags: android

I am working on legacy project. After some time I start to notice exceptionally long start up time. I revised log and found this exceptions continuously repeating two three times before application started.

```
05-08 18:09:05.182 1907-4834/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account: <ELLIDED:-1441199961>, App: com.google.android.gms, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contextcontroller
                                       efl: Long live credential not available.
                                           at efm.b(:com.google.android.gms:3117)
                                           at efm.a(:com.google.android.gms:119)
                                           at edt.a(:com.google.android.gms:437)
                                           at eds.a(:com.google.android.gms:31404)
                                           at eds.a(:com.google.android.gms:297)
                                           at flg.a(:com.google.android.gms:1189)
                                           at flf.a(:com.google.android.gms:480)
                                           at flf.a(:com.google.android.gms:185)
                                           at eaa.a(:com.google.android.gms:370)
                                           at eaa.a(:com.google.android.gms:225)
                                           at eai.a(:com.google.android.gms:1438)
                                           at eah.a(:com.google.android.gms:752)
                                           at eah.e(:com.google.android.gms:463)
                                           at eah.d(:com.google.android.gms:389)
                                           at eaf.b(:com.google.android.gms:549)
                                           at lhr.a(:com.google.android.gms:80)
                                           at lgj.a(:com.google.android.gms:53)
                                           at clx.a(:com.google.android.gms:7093)
                                           at cgy.run(:com.google.android.gms:55)
                                           at cgw.a(:com.google.android.gms:248)
                                           at cgw.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms:241)
                                           at lmi.run(:com.google.android.gms:142)
                                           at lmq.run(:com.google.android.gms:450)
                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                           at lra.run(:com.google.android.gms:17)
                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-08 18:09:05.182 1907-4834/? W/Auth: [GetToken] GetToken failed with status code: BadAuthentication
05-08 18:09:05.192 817-1328/? D/ActivityManager: bindService callerProcessName:com.google.android.gms, calleePkgName: com.google.android.gms, action: null
05-08 18:09:05.202 1907-4834/? W/Auth: [GoogleAuthUtil] GoogleAuthUtil
05-08 18:09:05.202 1907-4834/? W/AuthSessionAuthenticato: Auth related exception is being ignored: BadAuthentication
05-08 18:09:05.212 1907-4834/? E/ctxmgr: [BaseServerTask]Server task (WriteInterestRecordTask) got error statusCode=-1.
                                         com.android.volley.VolleyError: Unable to obtain auth token - is the device online?
                                             at clx.a(:com.google.android.gms:7113)
                                             at cgy.run(:com.google.android.gms:55)
                                             at cgw.a(:com.google.android.gms:248)
                                             at cgw.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms:241)
                                             at lmi.run(:com.google.android.gms:142)
                                             at lmq.run(:com.google.android.gms:450)
                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                             at lra.run(:com.google.android.gms:17)
                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-08 18:09:05.212 1907-4834/? E/ctxmgr: [SyncServerInterestRecordsOperation]Failed WriteInterestRecord: network status=-1
05-08 18:09:06.102 817-1349/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 2027
05-08 18:09:07.002 302-302/? E/SMD: DCD OFF
```

I am using com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0 if it is relevant.

Comment: Why don't you try with the latest google-services? 3.0.0

Comment: Now I am using 3.1.0, it has the same error.

Comment: @kirk_hehe how you solve your issue?? i am in same Situtation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getToken() failed. Status BAD\_AUTHENTICATION error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35967017/gettoken-failed-status-bad-authentication-error)