# Deleting Data from Firebase giving error "Bad Authentication"

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception

In a blog app, I have two activities Feed and single post `activity`.
Feed activities show all the posts and when user click on any post it opens in a single post activity.

In single post activity, I have menu giving the option to edit and delete the post.
On deleting, the post should be deleted and intent should take the user to feed activity but what happens is, post get deleted but intent doesn't execute and it shows the error given below.

Here is the code I wrote ithe n menu option

```
@Override
// Action on selecting the menu
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_edit) {

        // Add code to edit the post

    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_delete) {
   // Condition to test if the user who is deleting  the post is the same who posted it 
    if (PostUserName.getText().toString().equals(userName)) {

          // postkey is parent, which contains data of that single post
           dbref.child(postKey).removeValue();
           Intent toFeed = new Intent(SinglePostActivity.this, 
           FeedActivity.class);
           startActivity(toFeed);

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**Error Displayed**

> 11-20 16:20:48.808 1960-1979/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account: , App: com.android.vending, Service: androidmarket
>   edx: Long live credential not available.
>                                              at edy.b(:com.google.android.gms@11518470:10)
>                                              at edy.a(:com.google.android.gms@11518470:50)
>                                              at ecl.a(:com.google.android.gms@11518470:50)
>                                              at flk.a(:com.google.android.gms@11518470:8)
>                                              at flk.a(:com.google.android.gms@11518470:4)
>                                              at fkj.a(:com.google.android.gms@11518470:2)
>                                              at fkh.a(:com.google.android.gms@11518470:17)
>                                              at fkh.a(:com.google.android.gms@11518470:6)
>                                              at bsr.a(:com.google.android.gms@11518470:203)
>                                              at bsr.a(:com.google.android.gms@11518470:61)
>                                              at dzj.a(:com.google.android.gms@11518470:6)
>                                              at dzi.a(:com.google.android.gms@11518470:2)
>                                              at dzi.e(:com.google.android.gms@11518470:6)
>                                              at dzh.a(:com.google.android.gms@11518470:1)
>                                              at eax.getAuthToken(:com.google.android.gms@11518470:7)
>                                              at android.accounts.AbstractAccountAuthenticator$Transport.getAuthToken(AbstractAccountAuthenticator.java:244)
>                                              at android.accounts.IAccountAuthenticator$Stub.onTransact(IAccountAuthenticator.java:113)
>                                              at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
>                                              at buy.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@11518470:3)
>                                              at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)

**UPDATED**

Solved the problem by deleting my account info from the emulator and putting it again then by updating google play services and google play itself.

But, Now getting **Null Pointer Exception at line 125** , may be because the single post has been deleted and now single post activity has nothing to display. I know this is very basic but I'm new to coding and don't know how to tackle it. *here is the code*,

```
 String postUserName = (String) dataSnapshot.child("userId").getValue();
 String postTitle = (String) dataSnapshot.child("title").getValue();
 String postDesc = (String) dataSnapshot.child("desc").getValue();
 String postImage = (String) dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue();

 // line 125, which showed error.
//  and I would also like to know why the above String did not show the same error

 long postupVoteCount = (long) dataSnapshot.child("upVote").getValue();
 int upVotes = (int) postupVoteCount;
 long postDownVoteCount = (long) dataSnapshot.child("downVote").getValue();
 int downVotes = (int) postDownVoteCount;

 PostUserName.setText(postUserName);
 PostTitle.setText(postTitle);
 PostDesc.setText(postDesc);
 PostUpVoteCount.setText(Integer.toString(upVotes));
 PostDownVoteCount.setText(Integer.toString(downVotes));
```

Please Help.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35967017/gettoken-failed-status-bad-authentication-error) may be helpful.

Comment: @Mehmed. Thank you. It helped me but now getting  **Null pointer Exception** could you please look into that.  The post has been updated with details.