# laravel API and how can i send a token?

Tags: android, laravel

i am new in laravel i am android front-end devloper and start learning laravel for back-end. Can you please tell me how to pass URL in my android app code. I used retrofit for connect with android and php (laravel) i use passport for it but not working

**e/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account: , App: com.google.android.gms, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cclog**

this error shows.

Can you help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getToken() failed. Status BAD\_AUTHENTICATION error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35967017/gettoken-failed-status-bad-authentication-error)

Comment: Hello so you are new in api :Happy Coding:)

Comment: yes new in laravel api i used passport bt didint get token 
my url is 
 private static final String BASE_URL = "http://[IP address]/[project_name]/api